# How to debug where scrapy-splash freezes?

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash

I am using splash + lua script to parse Client-side rendering site.

Site is complicated, I need use a lot of `splash:wait()` stuff in loops. Example:

```
      while splash:select('#x-widget-1-label') ~= nil do
        splash:wait(0.1)
      end
```

And I see, that sometimes I am getting result, but in other times Lua script just "stuck" somewhere in my "wait" blocks. It happens rarely, but it shouldn't be happened at any circumstances.

How to debug in what block my script stucks?

Comment: `print("got here")`?

Comment: I can't see output, as script just stuck...

Comment: Save it to a file then? I mean you could also use `debug`, but that seems overengineered.